# Spinner not showing data

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using a spinner in my program and it gets data from my azure SQL database, but when i clicked the drop down nothing happens. Here is my code

```
    try {
        ConnectionHelper conStr = new ConnectionHelper();
        connect = conStr.connectionclass();
        String query = "select * from fabric";
        Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString("FABRIC_NAME");
            data.add(id);
        }
        String[] array = data.toArray(new String[0]);
        ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        Fabric.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Fabric.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            String name = Fabric.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Toast.makeText(Calc_140_plain.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

i cant seem to find an error in `LogCat` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your data array has some element

```
while (rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString("FABRIC_NAME");
            data.add(id);
        }
    Log.d("data","size:"+data.size());
```

print size after while to check data is not empty.

Try this:

```
ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
```

instead of:

```
ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
```

Comment: Still no display

Comment: Can we have a full chat about this with the stack messaging service, i can send you all the code there

Comment: did you check the size of data array?

Comment: Where do i insert this code `Log.d("data size",data.size()+"");` and where do i view it